# What's the latest version of Cloudera Manager and CDH?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm currently running on cloudera Manager 5.14.3 and CDH 5.14.2
and want to upgrade to a higher and more stable version. Which version is the most stable and advisable to upgrade to? Version 6 or version 7?

Answer (score 0):

In general Cloudera always recommends you to go the highest GA version of the big data platform.

However, be advised that Cloudera Manager 7 is actually the manager of the new generation of the platform: CDP.

As such you may need to check with your account team whether any additional steps are needed to upgrade to the platform. This is likely still worth looking into, as the CDH 6 end of life is approaching in about 18 months already.